# X SERVERにおけるサブドメインへの301リダイレクト処理の記述（.htaccess）

Tags: .htaccess

X SERVERで運用中のサイトにおいて、.htaccessの記述でご質問です。

実現したいこと（各サブドメインへのリダイレクト×2とURL統一です。）
・https://example.com/aaa/ → https://new.exmaple.com/aaa/ への301リダイレクト
・https://example.com/bbb/ → https://new.exmaple.com/bbb/ への301リダイレクト
・https://example.com/new/ → https://new.exmaple.com/ への301リダイレクト

課題：
example.com/.htaccessに下記記述をしていますが、ブラウザによってはリダイレクトされなかったり、最初の/aaa/だけしかリダイレクトされなかったりします。

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/aaa.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://new.example.com/aaa [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bbb.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://new.example.com/bbb [R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect permanent /new/ https://new.example.com/
```

デフォルトのWordPressの記述に追加しています。

### 追記

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/aaa.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://new.example.com/aaa [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bbb.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://new.example.com/bbb [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

上記のような記述に変更してもリダイレクトが反映がされませんでした。
キャッシュはクリアして確認しております。

Comment: 301でキャッシュしてしまっている可能性はないですか？まず試験的に302で行い、最後に301にしたほうがいいです。あとリダイレクト先は別サーバですか？`/new/`も`RewriteRule`に入れない理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。リダイレクト先のサブドメインは同じサーバ内です。`/new`のみ入れていない理由は、このリダイレクトだけちゃんと反映されるからです。`Redirect permanent /aaa https://new.example.com/aaa`の記述だとエラーが起きてしまいます。

Comment: パット見、変なところが思い当たりません。/newのリダイレクトはちゃんと反映されてるということですが、それははなぜですか？もしも 他にも設定ファイルなどがあれば、可能な限り 質問に記載するようにしてもらえますか？

Answer (score -1):

質問とは関係ない部分で気になりましたので。

```
# BEGIN WordPress
```

と

```
# END WordPress
```

の間に記載したものはWordPressによって書き換えられてしまう可能性がありますので、
WordPressで自動で記述されたもの以外は上記の外に書いたほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。`# BIGIN WordPress`～`# END WordPress`の外に記述した場合でも上手くいきませんでした。。。

Comment: すみません誤解させてしまいましたが、こちらは記載の通りご質問の回答ではありませんでした。この間に追加でなにかを書くとWordPressのシステムに消されてしまいますということをお伝えしたかっただけです。